# How to clear Login Attempts in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel's Auth Throttling feature and it is working correctly but I would like to know how to clear the login attempts for that email?
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authentication-throttling

currently the lockout time is at "Too many login attempts. Please try again in 5418 seconds"

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know how to ask for this, but your question helped me so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller that includes the `ThrottlesLogins` trait, create a new route handler method:

```
public function clearThrottle(Request $request) {
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    // Forward elsewhere or display a view
}
```

Answer (score 18):

run this in the console `php artisan cache:clear` and you're good to go